# Bounded linear operators on Banach Spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be Banach Spaces. Assume that $T: X\to Y$ is a linear operator and $S: Y\to Z$ is a bounded one-to-one linear operator.

*Show that $T$ is bounded if $SoT$ is bounded.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Closed Graph Theorem: let $x_n \to x$ and $T(x_n) \to y$. Then $S(T(x_n)) \to S(T(x))$  because $S\circ T$ is continuous. Also $ST(x_n) \to Sy$ because $S$ is continuous. Hence $S(T(x))=Sy$. Since $S$ is injective we get $y=Tx$.

Comment: It is actually sufficient that $S$ is closed and $\operatorname{ran}T\subset\operatorname{dom}S$ (instead that $S$ is bounded and defined everywhere).

Comment: @amsmath Sure. Good observation.